# JQuery submit queuing (synchronization)

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

My java script block of code:

```
$('#someButton').click(function () {

   $('#form1').submit();
   $('#form2').submit();     
   $('#form3').submit();
   $('#form4').submit();

   return false;

});
```

How to force these submits to be fired one by one.

submit1 fired >> submit1 ended >> submit2 fired >> submit2 ended >> submit3 fired >> submit3 ended >> ...

Comment: whether the forms are submitted using ajax?

Comment: You will have to submit the forms using ajax. Because when you submit one form, you will leave the page.

Comment: It would also be helpful to explain precisely what it is you mean by "synchronized". Do you want the submits to happen at the *same* time (not possible), or in the particular order? Do you want one submit to start only when the previous has completed, or something else?

Comment: Submit methods are overloaded in other place. They do not leave the page. I want only fire them from this `click()` one by one.

Comment: @Pointy Edited question to be more precise.

Comment: Are you submitting to an iframe?

Comment: @Spokey No, but what does it matter? I only want to force these submits to wait for previous to end.

Comment: It does matter because without a callback option you cannot make them wait for each other. It's important to know where you are submitting or exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Spokey It is strange what you are saying. It should not matter. Suppose I want to fire `function 2` after `function 1` ended. Do I have to know what are they doing inside? It should not be relevant.

Comment: If you have a `setTimeout` in `function 1` do you still know when it *truly* ended to run `function 2`? You have to call `function 2` in the timeout callback if you want the right order. Simply putting  function 2 after 1 won't be enough as it will run before the timeout. This is how submit works. It doesn't know when it finished because it's made to work asynchronous so it won't wait for the other to finish. You **have** to know what they do, set a callback and call the other submit. That's why it's important to tell us what they are doing.

Comment: @Spokey Callback will modify the submit methods code. I fire these submit from two places. I don't want them to be changed. In the second place.

Comment: Without changing them this is not possible.

Comment: @Spokey what about promises etc ? Any other method ?

Comment: @Spokey I created new more detailed question about the problem, I will delete this one soon. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274537/one-submit-button-for-multiple-forms-master-save-strategy

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your .submit() is an Ajax type submit you can implement the "success" method so that once the first one completes it calls the second .submit() and so on.

In jQuery - pseudocode

```
function submit1(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: submit2(),
  dataType: dataType
});
}

function submit2(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: submit3(),
  dataType: dataType
});
}
```

...

Comment: But I want to call `$('#form1').submit();` not create new methods.